# jQuery - Appending thumbnails from array of objects with specific index number(data-index)

Tags: jquery, arrays, indexing, foreach

First of all I am new to this and I am learning so do not judge my code too harshly.
I have an array of objects which include the src of images for thumbnails and need to append them to a container div where the thumbnails are displayed. But then I need to know which of these thumbnails was clicked. I am showing an example of one of the objects from array. I am using this structure of jQuery to append the thumbnails:

```
let avenue = {
photo: 'gallery/avenue.jpg',
title: 'Avenue',
description: 'Beautiful road with rays of sunlight coming through the mist'
```

};

```
let data = [avenue, school, street, block];
data.forEach((item,index) => {
let imgsrc = data[index].photo;
$('.thumbsbox').append('<img class="thumbnail" data-index="${index}" src= "'+imgsrc+'">');
    });
```

My problem is that It creates the thumbnails as it is supposed to but i need data-index to show an actual index number of the object from array. Now on inspect element it shows just: "${index}" on every single thumbnail.

**Any ideas how to make this data-index to be an actual index number of these objects?**

Thank you so much for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same way as you used to map the imgsrc, treat index variable as string. it should read +index+

```
$('.thumbsbox').append('<img class="thumbnail" data-index="'+index+'" src= "'+imgsrc+'">');
```

Comment: Oh my god! Thanks a lot. I am just learning and I knew I was so close but could not find the problem. Your solution worked! :) Thanks again.